# Configure Plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The two plot must be set tight to the figure window so that the date axis will be showen appropriate with it x label. I have tried `plt.subplots_adjust(..)` but in this case the changes will be applied just on one plot. Another soluation that I 've tried `fig1.tight_layout()` but it didn't work.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

EQ = {'2017-08-23 02:04:00':(18,1),'2017-08-23 02:05:00':(20,2),'2017-08-23 02:06:00':(12,3),'2017-08-23 02:07:00':(22,4)}
LIST_P1=[];LIST_P2=[];Time_P=[]
for j_p in EQ.keys():
        LIST_P1.append(EQ[j_p][1])
        LIST_P2.append(EQ[j_p][0])
        Time_P.append(time.mktime(time.strptime(j_p, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

dateconv=np.vectorize(datetime.fromtimestamp)
Date_F1=dateconv(Time_P)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ax1.plot_date(Date_F1,LIST_P1,'g-')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.grid(True)
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = plt.gca()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ax2.plot_date(Date_F1,LIST_P2,'g-')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y-axis',fontsize=14)
ax2.set_xlabel('X-axis',fontsize=14)
ax2.grid(True)
for label in ax2.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.07,right=0.985,bottom=0.16,top=0.955,hspace=0.200,wspace=0.200)
plt.show()
```

The plots should look like this:

[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.2]

Comment: Of course you would need to call `plt.subplots_adjust` for every figure you have, not only the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with the `45°` in `label.set_rotation()`. I have changed it to `15°` and it works.